Ads Archive API Not Returning Active Ads
I’m using the Facebook Ads Archive API to fetch ads with the following URL:
https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/ads_archive?access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN&search_terms=MY_SEARCH_TERM&ad_reached_countries=AE&fields=ad_creation_time,ad_delivery_start_time,ad_delivery_stop_time,ad_creative_bodies&limit=1000&ad_active_status=ALL
This URL returns ads as expected, but without the active ads. And when I modify the URL to filter only active ads:
https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/ads_archive?access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN&search_terms=MY_SEARCH_TERM&ad_reached_countries=AE&fields=ad_creation_time,ad_delivery_start_time,ad_delivery_stop_time,ad_creative_bodies&limit=1000&ad_active_status=ACTIVE
I get no data, even though I can see active ads matching this criteria manually in the Ads Library.Could someone please help me understand why this might be happening and how I can resolve it?
I expect to see all the active ads
